# Is it wrong to cite a source I did not use?

Tags: citations, ethics, undergraduate, research-undergraduate

I am writing a paper for an English class on a topic that I know well. for this paper, there is a minimum requirement for cited sources but I did not meet that requirement and was able to meet the length requirement for the paper.

Comment: If it is relevant, why not use it to back up your claims at the very least?

Comment: Since you're talking about an English class, there is no answer we can give you beyond "ask your teacher." The appropriate answer in an academic setting is not necessarily the one your teacher wants you to follow.

Comment: Not having the minimum number of citations may be a warning that you did not take a broad enough view of the topic. Are there issues or opinions you should have considered and didn't?

Comment: I am fairly sure the minimum requirement was not supposed to be a "minimum of stuff listed in the bottom", but more likely a "minimum of sources used".

Comment: In general academic writing, there is no such thing as a minimum number of sources: you cite as many as you need, which could, in rare cases, be none at all. So your question is about the precise rules of your course -- we don't know those. But, look, doesn't it seem dishonest to meet such a requirement by listing ten sources if you only use eight?

Answer (score 5):

Ask yourself: why did the Professor put this requirement?

It is almost certainly not just to make your life difficult.

A more likely explanation is that your professor wants you to not only provide your own analysis, but to back your analysis up with others' research and analysis.

So if you were to cite a source without using it, your mark won't likely go up, because your arguments are no better supported. Any good marker will see this. So if you're trying to increase your grade, you should add a source, and incorporate it into your arguments. In any case, I suspect your paper needs work to meet your professor's expectations.

Answer (score 2):

As a professor, I look at the bibliography of students' papers and I penalize students for including sources in their bibliography that are not cited in the paper. First, this could mean that they used ideas from that source, but did not credit the source for the exact material used in the paper. The other meaning is that they did not use the source, but just wanted to add to the bibliography. Personally, I would view this as academic dishonesty, because the student misused references to fraudulently meet requirements of the assignment. I don't know if your professor or others would view that the same way, but that's how I typically view it.

Another scenario is that a student puts a citation in-text and in the reference page, but the material cited has nothing to do with that reference. This would be more difficult to catch, unless the professor is an expert in the area the student is writing about, but this would be considered academic dishonesty, too.

If you have additional sources available that are relevant to the topic, it seems that finding material from the source to include somewhere in your paper and editing the paper would be easy and resolve the problem anyway, so why not just incorporate something (a sentence or two, even) into your paper?

Answer (score 0):

It's not wrong however you have to consider why you are using that source. Are you using it to fill up space in your bibliography/works cited?

Best practice is that if it wasn't your own idea you cite it.

Hope this helps.